# The type jakarta.validation.Payload cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

This error I get when I used `@CreditcardNumber` annotation in spring for validation rule on credit card number.

I try to rebuild maven dependency added javax validator's latest dependency.
It occurred in two files but removing one Annotation resolve both but validation not works.
I was learning this example from spring in action edition 5

Order.java

```
package tacos;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Order {

private Long id;
private Date createdAt;
     
 @NotBlank(message="no name")
 
  private String name;
 

 @NotBlank(message="no street")
  private String street;
 
 @NotBlank(message="no city")
  private String city;
 
 @NotBlank(message="no state")
  private String state;
 

 @NotBlank(message="no zip")
  private String zip;
 
 @CreditCardNumber
 String ccNumber;
 

@Pattern(regexp="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$",
message="Must be formatted MM/YY")         
 
  private String ccExpiration;
@Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
 
  private String ccCVV;

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
package tacos.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry viewRegistry) {
        viewRegistry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        viewRegistry.addViewController("/abc").setViewName("home");
        viewRegistry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Comment: You are probably using the, up until now, the unsupported Hibernate Validator 7 library. Instead just add `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead of messing around with individual dependencies yourself, that way you get the correct ones.